# Passing date as string to backend and server

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is is appropriate client side pass date as string as param to backend? Eg. `10-05-2019`. What's the drawback? I'm dealing with application that involve transactions (booking/appointment), and I'm not sure about this.

Comment: It is okay, till your backend server accepts that format.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to pass data as string - but if your system will works with many timezones then first convert local browser time to UTC0 (+00:00 - zulu Z) and then send to serwer. On serwer site operate only on UTC0 date-times which will be "common denominator" for different time zones.

```js
let s= new Date("05-10-2019");

console.log(s);
```